# Prove $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B)$ when $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$.

Tags: probability

essentially I just need to prove the above and that will hopefully show that any probability of 1 is independent of event.

Comment: It will be easier if you first consider $\bar{A}$. $P(\bar{A})=0$. You prove that $\bar{A},B$ are independent. Then this leads to independence of $A,B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually any event $A$ that always happens is of course independent from any other event $B$, as the absence of presence of $B$ has no effect on the absence or presence of $A$ ... it's present!

Mathematically, we thus have:

$$P(A|B)=P(A|B^C)=P(A)=1$$

And we *always* have that:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)\cdot P(B)$$

Hence:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)\cdot P(B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$$

Comment: Don't we need the constraint of $\mathbb{P}(B) \in (0,1)$ or $\mathbb{P}(B^{\complement}) \in (0,1)$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)$ and $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B^{\complement})$ are well defined?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Yeah, that would be good ....

Answer (score 5):

We have $P(A^c\cap B)\leqslant P(A^c)=0$, so $P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)=P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

In this case

$$
P(A\cap B) = P(B) = P(A)P(B)
$$